# Find all the missing directed edges in an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, numpy, graph-theory

I use a `numpy` matrix to represent a directed graph, like this:

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 0
```

Given such a matrix, I want to find all the missing directed edges for which there exists a directed edge in opposite direction.

For example, in the matrix above, for node `1` (indexed 0), edges `1 -> 2` and `1 -> 3` are missing in this sense as there exist edges `2 -> 1` and `3 -> 1` in the other direction. Similarly, edge `3 -> 2` is missing too as there exists edge `2 -> 3`.

The actual matrices in my application is large, e.g. thousands of nodes, and the algorithm for finding such edges must be fast. A brute force way is to check every pairs (which are symmetrical given the main diagonal of the matrix) and see if an edge is missing between the two.

I wonder if there is an more efficient way (provided by `numpy` perhaps?) to do it. Some linear algebra tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your example slightly to show a case in which a pair of nodes is connected in both directions.  Here is a way to do it with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0]]).astype(bool)

A = A
print A.astype(int)
B = A.transpose() & ~A
print B.astype(int)
```

This should give:

```
[[0 1 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 0 0]]
[[0 0 1]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 1 0]]
```

which I believe is what you want.  If your matrix is extremely large, you might consider using sparse matrices instead, but the principle is the same.

**Explanation**:

For any edge, A[i,j], the reverse of that edge is A[j,i].  A[j,i] is the same as A.transpose()[i,j].  Therefore, A.transpose() is the adjacency matrix for you graph if you reverse the direction of each edge.  The ~ operator is equivalent to the np.logical_not function.  The values of ~A are 1 wherever there is not an edge.  You are interested in "missing connections", connections which are not in A but are in A.transpose().  You obtain those connections using the & operator, which is equivalent to np.logical_and, on A.transpose() and ~A.

Comment: thanks that works, but could you explain a bit about the logic behind `A.transpose() & ~A`?

Comment: all makes sense. Thanks! The only detail missing: the elements of `~A` is actually `[[-1, -2, -1], [-2, -1, -2], [-2, -1, -1]]`, where the `0`s in A are turned into `-1`s, and `1`s are turned into `-2`s. Then the `&` operation is actually based on the two's complement representation of the these values.

Comment: Just to add, `~` operation is the bitwise negation on the binary form of the integers (`0`s and `1`s)

Comment: Nice catch.  I hadn't noticed that behavior.  It still worked, but it would probably be cleaner to convert A into a boolean array.  I'll make that edit.

Answer (score 0):

An adjacency matrix like this should be symmetric. What about taking the lower triangular portion, transposing it and comparing it to the upper triangular portion? Something like this:

```
low = tril(m).transpose()
upp = triu(m)
missing = mod(low + upp, 2)
```

`missing` should be 1 where there are missing locations in the upper triangular portion.

If all you care about it making sure the upper portion is right, you could just do something like:

```
m = tril(m).transpose() + tril(m)
```

Comment: *"An adjacency matrix like this should be symmetric."*  Not for a directed graph.

Comment: @Warren, you're right of course. I read the question as being an undirected graph, based on his description of what he was trying to do. I should've read it more carefully.